# C# EntityFramework Core настройка отношения many-to-many

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core, relation, many-to-many

Подход использую code-first. У меня есть две таблицы с отношением m2m:

```
public sealed record AuthorEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookEntity> Books { get; set; }
}

public sealed record BookEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AuthorEntity> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Связаны они через третью:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AuthorEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.HasMany(e => e.Books)
            .WithMany(b => b.Authors)
            .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
            "AuthorsBooks",
            t => t
                .HasOne<BookEntity>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("BookId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),
            t => t
                .HasOne<AuthorEntity>()
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey("AuthorId")
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        );
    }
```

Код для теста:

```
var a = new AuthorEntity
{
    Name = "a1",
    Books = new[] { new BookEntity { Name = "b1" } }
};

db.Authors.Add(a);
db.SaveChanges();

var b = new BookEntity
{
    Name = "b2",
    Authors = new[] { new AuthorEntity { Name = "a1" } }
};

db.Books.Add(b);
db.SaveChanges();
```

При выполнении второго запроса в базу вылетает исключение:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Authors' with unique index 'IX_Authors_Name'. The duplicate key value is (a1).

Можно ли сконфигурировать отношение так, чтобы orm выполняла вставку в таблицу только если записи еще нет? И если нет, то как выполнять такую вставку?

Comment: У вас два раза используется SaveChanges в коде. Закомментируйте первое.

Comment: При работе приложения SaveChanges будет вызываться при каждой вставке. Не понимаю, как это может помочь.

Я немного переделал код, создал два объекта контекста и выполнил вставку по очереди: в первом -- автора, во втором -- книги. Исключение осталось тем же.

Comment: EF оперирует такой вещью, как Unit of Work. Внутри этого UoW он автоматом создаст все связи в базе, а вы разбиваете отдельными SaveChanges. Посмотрите как сделано всегда в любых примерах по многие-ко-многим ([тынц образец1](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php), [образец2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4253165/5752652)): а) сущности создаются по отдельности б) сохранение общее. Увидели общий using во втором примере? У вас приложение устроено так, что этот using разрывается? Ну, значит придётся что-то ещё переделывать. А сущности добавляйте отдельно.

Comment: `Authors = new[] { a }` - при создании книги `b2` используйте уже готового автора

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Тут можно отметить комментарий правильным ответом?